# Apply custom style to react-select & best practice

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, react-select

Essentially, I want to maintain the style of my input fields with that of a react-select component. I've learned that styled-components would be the best course of action, but am still not sure which styles to change to get my desired result. I'd like to remove the border, focus glow, and make it inline, while maintaining everything else. Would I make changes to .Select-menu-outer?

[Here is an example of one of my custom input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEB2X.png)

[Here is my css style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnBjI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the documentation for react-select to do styling to its components.

```
const customStyles = {
  container: base => {(
    ...base,
    backgroundColor: {/* Your color */}
  )},
  option: base => {(
    ...base,
    backgroundColor: {/* Your color */}
  )}
}

<Select styles={customStyles} />
```

You can style many components of react-select by that. You just need to target the right component and you can even use states with that.